# How does Klarna remain in business when all a customer needs to pay with Klarna is a simple phone number?

Tags: fraud, online-payment

I just ordered my first product using Klarna's buy-now-pay-later online payment service.
I was shocked to find out that all they want from you is a valid phone number. Once you've entered it they'll send you a confirmation code and after confirming it the payment is made.

They don't ask for your id, they don't ask for proof of residence, isn't this online payment method incredibly fraud sensitive? I can imagine people simply using burner phone numbers or throw-away prepaid SIM cards to make payments with Klarna for free. Sure Klarna can ask the merchant to give the shipping address, but what if that shipping address is a parcel collection point at some supermarket or the address of a motel room?

What does Klarna do to prevent people from using its service for free without ever paying back the money owed?

Comment: That isn't really a personal finance question. Contact the company, tell them that not knowing makes you uncomfortable, and ask them

Comment: Complete guess: they might run some checks on the phone number (possibly with the vendor; credit agencies or other public-ish sources) to see if it's "legit". If there's no match (as would be the case with a burner phone) they may ask more questions before making payment.

Comment: @keshlam the topic of this stackexchange is personal finance ANNNNDDD?!?!?!!? You guessed it... MONEY. The downvotes are truly appalling btw

Comment: This has been addressed repeatedly in Meta. The intended reading is "Personal (Finance and Money)". You're far from the first person to get that wrong, but I've had no luck convincing SE that it's something which should be fixed.

Comment: Their website states they do a soft credit pull when you make a purchase. Did you actually purchase something and get a payment plan or just sign up for the app?

Comment: @Nosjack, i made a small purchase. About 28 EUR

Comment: A phone number is a LOT of information. They have now linked a phone number to a transaction (assuming you used it). It's now *TWO* phones' info they have (two parties involved in the transaction), the transaction amount, functionally where you two were when the transaction happened. Then if a crime was actually involved, subpoena for all the records related to the two phones, and you basically can arrest the two people already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I have no idea what Klarna’s system or model is, a few points:

- In many countries, “burner phones” just don’t exist. You have to provide ID, which is recorded, even to get a prepaid SIM. While it will require police or judicial proceedings to get the info, it should still be enough of a deterrent for many people.
- Add a few more things like an IP address (which can very often be
  traced back), an e-mail address, and more, and you get quite a bit of
  info on the user.
- If you bought goods to be delivered, then you also have a name and address (which they get from the merchant)
- If you are a returning customer, the merchant could also provide information on that (it would be quite limited due to privacy concerns, but there must be ways around that — or you may have agreed to that information sharing).
- They may apply more or less checks depending on whatever info they have. For instance, if the phone number is from a country where ID is not required, they could ask for more info.
- Likewise, they could ask for more or less info depending on the amount of the purchase.
- In some countries, people are just expected to pay. In Switzerland, “we’ll send you an invoice” is a common thing (or at least used to be, offline — while this is probably different nowadays, especially online, there is still a lot more trust than there could be in other countries).

It is the job of companies granting credits to build risk models so they can decide if they will grant you credit depending on a variety of parameters. Some are quite good at making a decision based on a very small amount of data. Don’t worry, like insurers, they will build the cost of that risk in their fees (to you and/or to the merchant). It may be worth it for the merchant to pay more fees for a “frictionless” user experience which greatly improved their conversion rates.

Also note that AML/CTF regulations mean that beyond a give amount (per transaction, or total), they **have to** ask for ID and other documents. Your transaction was a very small one, it’s in their interest to take a slightly higher risk on such transactions to “hook” you and use their services again for larger or frequent transactions (which mean more fees for them), and you will probably be more inclined to give them more information now that you have satisfactorily used their services.